# How to properly detect corners using Harris detector with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm testing some image processing to obtain ***minutiae*** from digital fingerprints. I'm doing so far:

1. Equalize histogram
2. Binarize
3. Apply Zhang-Suen algorithm for lines thinning (this is not working properly).
4. Try to determine corners in thinned image and show them.

So, the modifications I'm obtaining are:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, I can't get to obtain possible corners in the last image, which belongs to `thinned` instance of `Mat` object.

This is code for trying to get corners:

```
corners_image = cornerHarris(thinned,1,1,0.04)
corners_image = dilate(corners_image,None)
```

But trying `imshow` on the resulting matrix will show something like:

[image]

a **black image**.

How should I determine corners then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `cv::cornerHarris` returns corener responses, not corners itself. Looks like responses on your image is too small.

If you want to visualize corners you may get responses which are larger some `threshold` parameter, then you may mark this points on original image as follows:

```
corners = cv2.cvtColor(thinned, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
threshold = 0.1*corners_image.max()
corners [corners_image>threshold] = [0,0,255]
cv2.imshow('corners', corners)
```

Then you can call `imshow` and red points will correspond to corner points. Most likely you will need to tune threshold parameter to get results what you need.

See more details in [tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html).

Comment: I tried something like that before but it failed complaining about some numpy issue, I think as the image was a binary and trying to modify on a 3-sized list

Comment: Ok, it's my fault. I updated answer. I just need to convert binary image to BGR color space.